# hoisting behavior changed between chrome 48 and 49 ?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
if (true) {
  function test() {
    console.log(true);
  }
} else {
  function test() {
    console.log(false);
  }
}

test()
```

Chrome 48 (and node <5.9.1) logs false, chrome 49 (and firefox) log true. I guess they optimized by not hoisting from the falsy branch, but that can break existing applications.
Which one is correct according to spec?

Comment: Per the dupe, it looks like Chrome 49 added support for declaring functions in this fashion, and any code written in this way before probably wasn't working as intended in earlier versions of Chrome anyway, so any existing applications that looked like they _were_ working were actually broken already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function, the ECMAScript standard is to re-hoist function declarations in block statements for conditional creation, which is what Chrome 49 appears to be doing.

Prior to ECMAScript 6, however, the behavior of declaring functions in conditional blocks was undefined - browsers could use that conditional creation mechanism, hoist the first (or last) function they see (which is what Chrome 48 appears to do), not hoist either function and return an error on `test();`, or even do something non-JavaScript related that could end up setting your computer on fire.